# How can I setup Redhat to authenticate users to ActiveDirectory

Tags: linux, active-directory, redhat

We have a bunch of RedHat Enterprise Linux servers, and Windows workstations hooked up to Active Directory.

I was wondering how to setup RedHat so it would use ActiveDirectory to authenticate SSH user logins.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm a fan of [Likewise Open](http://www.likewise.com/products/likewise_open/) because of easy AD integration, but you can configure this directly.

- `/usr/bin/system-config-authentication`
  can be used to configure this in the
  GUI.
- `/usr/bin/authconfig` can be
  used to configure this in the CLI.

Comment: Crap, 8 seconds too slow!

Comment: At least you have good taste :D

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your answer moshen is that it doesn't actually provide any information as to how to use these tools to do the configuration.

A link to walkthrough would have been more helpful to the original requestor.  A link like http://blog.wains.be/2011/04/11/authenticate-linux-red-hat-with-microsoft-active-directory/ for example.